# How to display webp image format in native UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webp

Received html string with webp images sourced within it. Need to display these webp images within iOS native uiwebview.

Any suggestion please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step to support webp image in uiwebview as :

1) Get webp image url.
2) Use thirdParty library such as SDImageView to download image.
3) Using Base64 library, we can embed same data with `<img src>` tag.